# How do create an Alphabetizer Program?

Tags: html, arrays, alphabetical

This is what i have so far- could i have some help with getting the "alphabetized" version to show up? I've been trying to add different things, but i'm not sure what should stay and what should go. Could I get some tips on how to fix this up?

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title> Alphabetizer</title>
    </head>

    <body>


    <script>
    <p id="words"></p>
    function sumbitFunction(); {
    var words = document.getElementById("words"); 
    var input= input.sort();
    words.textContent = input.join();
    }
    </script>  

    <form>
    <form id="inputText">
    <input type="text" name="text here" value="write here" size= 100 
    value=40>
   <input type="button" 
   onclick="sumbitFunction() " value="Go"
   </form>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: A good place to start, at least for HTML/JS questions, is using jsbin.com or jsfiddle.net to make it easier for others to start working with your code.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/Lvd5ecqu/1/

```
 <html>
    <head>
        <title> Alphabetizer</title>
    </head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var submitFunction = function() {
            var words = document.getElementById("words").value.split(" ");
            var input = words.sort();
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = input.join();
            }
        </script>
    <body>
        <p id="output"></p>
        <form>
            <form id="inputText">
                <input id="words" type="text" name="text here" value="write here" size= 100 value=40>
                <input type="button" onclick="submitFunction() " value="Go" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: your fiddle has a space between the 1 and 00 in the size for the input